# Align Bootstrap button to right side of the navbar

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am just learning bootstrap and I don't know how to align the button to the right inside of my navbar.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <button type="button" class="btn container">Login</button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use `.ml-auto` and you have to delete `.container` from the button.

The class `.justify-content-between` would have an impact to other elements in the navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <button type="button" class="btn ml-auto">Login</button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
  <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
   <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>

</nav>
```

navbar have a display type of flex so use justify content between that will set the justify content property to space-between so that your content will be in the right side.Enclose with required divs to achieve the required output.